# Paperclip file field not working sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

I am developing a Rails application which uses Paperclip to save a picture in a model. In order to save this picture, I have a form_for which use a file input to save the picture. I haven't had any problem uploading the picture but sometimes it's not working. Most of time I receive a parameter like this:

```
"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000061faeb8 
  @original_filename="sample8.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg",
  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"service[picture]\"; 
  filename=\"sample.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
  @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20141026-3030-s39mpm>>,
```

With this type of parameters I get to upload the picture. However, sometimes I receive a parameter like this: "picture" => "sample.jpg", so I get the following error:

```
No handler found for "sample.jpg".
```

I have been surfing on Internet trying to find a similar question but I have not found anything. Does anyone know why this is happening?

This are the main files that I have use:

```
= form_for service, url: service_path( service ), html: { method: :put } do |f|
  = file_field_tag :picture, value: service.picture,
    id: "selected_file_service_#{ service.id }", class: 'selected_file_service',
    size: '24', name: "service[picture]", rel: service.id
  %input#browseButton.upload_picture.service_upload.service_picture_upload{
    type: "button", value: I18n.t( 'abadi.actions.upload_picture' ) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I need to use **multipart: true** in the form in the html parameter.